# Out of bounds exception on incrementing variable

Tags: c#

I've been while out of C# and MVC. And I am really struggling with the following error, I really don't see it. I have a list of restrictions and i want to add their keys to an string[].

```
int cntr = 0;
//loop through restrictions and add to array
foreach (var Restriction in this.admingroupRepository.Context.AdminRestrictions.ToList())
{
    currentRestrictionKeys[cntr] = Restriction.Key;
    cntr += 1;
}
```

This is the error i get on the cntr += 1 line:

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

I don't understand where this comes from, the foreach breaks before the cntr is out of the array's bounds right?

Comment: What is the type of `currentRestrictionKeys`?

Comment: how do you declare your `currentRestrictionKeys` variable?

Comment: string[] let me update me initial post, sorry.

Comment: Because you guys asked these questions i realized what i was doing wrong. I can't beleive i am stumped on something so simple..

Comment: Happens to everyone ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have allocated too little space for `currentRestrictionKeys`. But you don't really need to preallocate it at all; you can just use a trivial projection with LINQ:

```
var currentRestrictionKeys = this.admingroupRepository.Context.AdminRestrictions
                                 .Select(r => r.Key)
                                 .ToArray();
```